# Scala finding more elegant way

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to Scala and functional programming.

I was solving problem where you have to read number, and then that number of integers. After that you should calculate sum of all digits in all the integers.

Here is my code

```
def sumDigits(line: String) = 
    line.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.toInt - '0'.toInt)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val numberOfLines = Console.readInt
    val lines = for (i <- 1 to numberOfLines) yield Console.readLine   
    println(lines.foldLeft(0)( _ + sumDigits(_)))
  }
```

Is there more elegant or efficient way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sumDigits()` can be implemented easier with `sum`:

```
def sumDigits(line: String) = line.map(_.asDigit).sum
```

Second `foldLeft()` can also be replaced with `sum`:

```
lines.map(sumDigits).sum
```

Which brings us to the final version (notice there is no `main`, instead with extend `App`):

```
object Main extends App {

    def sumDigits(line: String) = line.map(_.asDigit).sum

    val lines = for (_ <- 1 to Console.readInt) yield Console.readLine   
    println(lines.map(sumDigits).sum)

}
```

Or if you really want to squeeze as much as possible in one line, inline `sumDigits` (not recommended):

```
lines.map(_.map(_.asDigit).sum).sum
```

Comment: Since you are doing a good job already, I gave up on my answer. Replace the `toInt` substraction with a single `_.asDigit`, though.

Comment: More bonus points: convert the outer `map` into `flatMap`, and drop the internal `.sum`. The result can also be converted into a for-comprehension which then gets `sum`ed.

Answer (score 4):

I like compact code, so I might (if I was really going for brevity)

```
object Reads extends App {
  import Console._
  println( Seq.fill(readInt){readLine.map(_ - '0').sum}.sum )
}
```

which sets the number of lines inline and does the processing as you go.  No error checking, though.  You could throw in a `.filter(_.isDigit)` right after the `readLine` to at least discard non-digits.  You might also `def p[A](a: A) = { println(a); a }` and wrap the reads in `p` so you can see what had been typed (by default on some platforms at least there's no echo to screen).

Answer (score 1):

One-liner Answer:

```
 Iterator.continually(Console.readLine).take(Console.readInt).toList.flatten.map(_.asDigit).sum
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you have to do some kind of parsing on `line` to break apart the existing decimal integers sub-strings:

```
val numbers = "5 1 4 9 16 25"
val ints = numbers.split("\\s+").toList.map(_.toInt)
```

Then you want to pull off the first one as the count and keep the rest to decode and sum:

```
val count :: numbers = ints
```

Then use the built-in sum method:

```
val sum = numbers.sum
```

Altogether in the REPL:

```
scala> val numbers = "5 1 4 9 16 25"
numbers: String = 5 1 4 9 16 25

scala> val ints = numbers.split("\\s+").toList.map(_.toInt)
ints: List[Int] = List(5, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25)

scala> val count :: numbers = ints
count: Int = 5
numbers: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)

scala> val sum = numbers.sum
sum: Int = 55
```

If you want to do something with the leading number count, you could verify that it's correct:

```
scala> assert(count == numbers.length)
```

Which produces no output, since the assertion passes.

Comment: He wanted *sum of digits* of integers.